# how to characterize a polynomial improvement over two quantities?

Tags: polynomials, algorithms, computational-complexity

Algorithm A runs in $n^k$ times. A new algorithm B which runs in $(n^k)^{\frac{2}{3}}$ was devised. Does B constitute a polynomial improvement over A? How to know if it is a polynomial improvement or not.

Comment: You mean big $O(n^k)$?

Comment: @Klangen Yes I do